# unable to fadeTo for class to replace non css compatible code for IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a  tag like this

```
 <a href="index.html" class="logo-title"></a>
```

I also have this code that does some stuff on page load stored in a js file that is called ... it all works apart from one thing ...

```
$.cookie('index_viewed', '1');
$(document).ready(function() {
     if ($.cookie("index_viewed") == 1) {
       return;
     } else {
       setTimeout(function() {
         $("#loader-wrapper .loader-section, #textbit, #logo, #wrapper").hide("slow"); 
         $("#wrapper").unwrap();
         $.cookie("index_viewed", 1);
         $( ".logo-title" ).fadeTo( "3000", 1.0 );

       }, 11000);
     }
 });
```

**I can't seem to get the fadeTo of .logo-title to fade after the 11 seconds... everything else works though which is great , can anyone help.**

the css of the class ....

```
.logo-title{
  background-image: url("../images/mthc/logo-whole.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 250px;
  border: 0 ;
  height: 180px;
  width:780px;
  z-index : 2500;
  opacity:0;
}
```

EDIT - HAVE NOW DONE THIS INDEPENDENTLY ON THE INDEX PAGE AND SEEMS TO WORK...

```
if ($.cookie("index_viewed") == 1) {
setTimeout(function() {
$( ".logo-title" ).fadeTo( 3000, 1 );
}, 5000);
};
```

Comment: Sorry my answer was wrong, was confused with other script I was working on haha. Lol.

Comment: Does everything else work? Also try `fadeTo(3000, 1.0 )`

Comment: thanks for the tip but it didn't work either

Comment: it is a very strange connundrum

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2ybtgzmz/

Comment: yeah i got the same thing when i did the scripts independent of the above code .. why it doesn't work in with the other code though is perhaps the question here

Comment: I have now done this in the index page which seemed to work